# Apache Drill unusably slow with S3 data source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-drill

I am trying to use Apache Drill with an S3 bucket, but it is incredibly slow.

I have about 20,000 JSON files. I can get results from them locally in a few seconds, e.g.:

```
> select count(*) from dfs.`/path/to/my/files/*.json`;
```

returns after less than 2 seconds.

Trying to run the exact same query on the exact same files in an S3 bucket is failing to complete even after 10 minutes:

```
> select count(*) from s3.`releases`;
```

Why is this? I thought the whole point of Drill was that it was fast on big datasets.

My S3 connection itself is OK, e.g. `SHOW files` shows me my available folders just fine in a reasonable amount of time, and there's nothing wrong with my network connection either.

Comment: S3 is not a file system!

Comment: I know S3 is not a file system. However, from the Drill docs, I assumed I could use it as a fast data source for Drill - but maybe not?

Comment: why did you expect it will be _fast data source_ ?

Comment: I'm an idiot, I guess. I assumed Drill would do some magic to make it fast.

Comment: you're certainly not an idiot - the s3 storage plugin for drill is nice but by no means its fast, specially if you have to run against many files in S3

Comment: @FrédéricHenri thanks for the reassurance :) Do you know if there are any fast in-cloud storage options for Drill? I like Drill because it doesn't require you to specify a schema upfront, but my data needs to live in the cloud rather than locally.

Comment: will continue to say AWS Athena is worth looking in such cases

Comment: @FrédéricHenri sadly Athena doesn't work for me, I need something that's schema-on-discovery rather than needing to specify the schema upfront.

Comment: AWS Glue crawlers can help to auto-discover schema in such cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not a direct answer to your question but you should look at [athena](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html) if you want to query on s3 bucket and you have large dataset